# Why $d(f(x,y)dx)=df(x,y) \wedge dx$

Tags: differential-geometry

Who can tell me why $d(f(x,y)dx)=df(x,y) \wedge dx$?

Comment: @Babak S.: Is that $0$?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Note that $d^2x=d(dx)=0$.

Comment: So we have $d(fdx)=dfdx$. But is $df \wedge dx=dfdx$? I want to know what $df \wedge dx$ is equal to...

Comment: Ian, $df$ is a $1$-form, as is $dx$, so what is $dfdx$ supposed to mean? $df\wedge dx$ is the product of $df$ and $dx$ in the exterior algebra and is a $2$-form (as expected).

Comment: You're on a roll today $\large \;+1^{+^\checkmark}$

Comment: @BabakS.: Agree with amWhy +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Express both sides in coordinates (as $g(x,y) dx\wedge dy$), directly evaluating the exterior derivative. You don't even need to use the fact that $d^2x=0$, as the term will appear on both sides.